# Python IO performance tuning

Tags: java, python-3.x, performance, io

Consider the code which stores json array into file:

**Python**

```
import json
with open('C:\\my_file.json', 'w') as file:
    array = [0] * 1000000000
    array = [0 for i in range(1000000000)]
    json.dump(array, file)
```

**Java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author nsheremet
 */
public class Reshaper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        int[] array = new int[1000000000];
        Arrays.fill(array, 0);
        mapper.writeValue(new File("C:\\myfile.json"), array);
    }
}
```

Java code takes about 1 minute to complete. While for python I have t wait about 40-60 minutes. Also for java I see about 250Mb/sec speed for writing file, while python code do this so slow that I can not detect thi via process explorer.

Why there is so big performance gap? For modern PC (Threadripper 1900) generate 1Gb+ file for 40-60 minutes is too much. Looks like some settings missed in python, is it?

Python version is 3.7.3

Java 1.8_131

OS: Windows 10

Comment: In general you can say that Java is faster than Python because of its Just-In-Time Compiler and because Python is an Interpreter language. But I don't think this explains that big difference. Do you know if the array initialization or the IO is slow?

Comment: @AndiCover First of all I am not saying that JIT is faster. Python have C++ optimized code both for json and io so it is not clear what is faster. Second, even if python is lower then java there should be such difference, may be 2 or 3 times, not 10+. The code is very simple CPU is powerful. I have mentioned is in the question, that java writes file with speed 250MB/sec while python much slower.

Comment: Thats basically what I said. My question was if you are sure that IO is slow or if it is your loop where you are setting the array values.